# Data structure behind a calendar

Tags: c#, java, data-structures, calendar, schedule

I'm on a project where I've got to create a program so that people can generate a class schedule.

I was going to create my calendar class and I was wondering about the type of data structure I should use to store the events.

I've heard a few times that generating schedules could be handles with graphs. If so, I'd be looking for some information about it. Otherwise, how should I store the events?

The way I thought I could store the events would be based on a time range in a day. The ultimate goal of this, is to generate schedules...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always implement **Calendar Queues**. The name is a metaphor alluding to a personal appointment calendar, with one page for each day, and each page listing the appointments one has on that day.

They're amazing with its **O(1)** time complexity.

You can see detailed information of implementation on [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.69.3472%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=TENZUNqxNIXc9ASEioG4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEeKNAKyApOgGMp6KcHSgg-m1ncsA&sig2=WJITQzR6OyMWfboJcV7cIg).